# Date time zone incorrect

Tags: data-loader

I am configured as (GMT-05:00) Central Daylight Time (America/Chicago) Time zone in salesforce.. I am trying to export case history and all the date fields are exported in GMT.

Where as when I create the report in salesforce and extract the data it is showing correctly in CDT...The data is actually stored in CDT...

I want the date/time in CDT time zone when i export the date through data loader. Can anyone please help with this...

I also i tried setting below values for time zone in data loader:
GMT-5:00
CDT
America/Chicago
but none of them worked,still i got the results in GMT..

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce stores ALL data in GMT or what's now called UTC code. When it's displayed, its then converted into the local time zone appropriate to the context User. So when the data was created by a user in CDT, it was converted to the equivalent GMT time when it was stored on the server.

When you create your reports, the data is being converted to your user context which once again is CDT. That's why it appears as you expect it to appear.

I hope that explains why when you attempt to export it, its being exported in GMT. You'll need to adjust all of your data after export for the 5 hour difference.

Answer (score -2):

"I have verified both Case history and report export, observed that the time is GMT only.Salesforce saves everything in GMT only if I'm not wrong.Can you please double check.

Regards,

Naveen

SSE , Salesforce CI expert group

http://www.autorabit.com